# giving extra information on model __unicode__ from another model

Tags: django, models

I've got two models controlling a loot system.

```
class Boss(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    instance = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    difficulty = models.ForeignKey(Difficulty)
    loot_table = models.ManyToManyField(Loot)


class Loot(models.Model):
    wh_item_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="Wowhead Item ID", max_length=255)
    wh_item_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Wowhead Item Name", max_length=255)
    gear_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lockout_tier = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s [%s]' % (self.wh_item_name, self.wh_item_id)
```

In the Loot model I am returning the wh_item_name and wh_item_id, but what I need it to return is the Loot.wh_item_name and [Boss.difficulty].

But looking at this I haven't the faintest clue where to start, I've tried filtering the boss model where the Loot is found in loot_table but I can't quite get there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your models are right. You have a many-to-many relationship between Boss and Loot, where as the name implies each Loot has multiple Bosses. So there isn't a single value for "boss.difficulty", but potentially several.

If that's what you want, you can simply concatenate them:

```
', '.join(self.boss_set.values_list('difficulty', flat=True)
```

but I suspect what you actually want is a ForeignKey from Loot to Boss, which will mean that each Loot just has a single Boss, so that you can simply output `self.boss.difficulty`.

**Edit**

```
def __unicode__(self):
    difficulties = ', '.join(self.boss_set.values_list('difficulty', flat=True)
    return u'%s [%s]' % (self.wh_item_name, difficulties)
```

Comment: I had it the other way around, but then encountered another problem a while back so tun it was suggested that I went about it this way.

Comment: Also a boss has many items, but the items could potentially have more than one boss.

Comment: OK, so you do have a good reason to have the many-to-many, in which case you can use the solution I gave above.

Comment: I'm a little confused as how to implement that.

Comment: You can assign it to a variable and use it in place of `self.wh_item_id`.

Comment: Forgive me, I think I may be being an idiot, but I still don't understand. More so, The will only ever be a single value for boss.difficulty it's a foreign key itself. each boss will only ever have one difficulty, so why would I need to concatenate them?

Comment: Because, as you said yourself, you have multiple *bosses*, each of which has a difficulty. That's what you need to concatenate.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain then, but could you possible show me an example of how this would fit into my model? I've tried it already but getting all sorts of errors.

Comment: That's giving me a syntax error. although I can't see anything wrong with it :/

Comment: as I expected, the example you gave did not return what I was after. It's coming back as [ 1, L] when it only needs to return just the difficulty (for example, [Normal] or [Heroic]